# URL and string interpolation

Tags: swift, swift3

It seems URL initializer (string: "") refuses to initialize properly when using string interpolation. The problem is, when I use something like

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.1")
```

it works, but the following

```
let host = "192.168.1.1"
let url = URL(string: "http://\(host)")
```

does not and url = nil.

In Playground both work but not in the code. I did double check if the variable host is properly set.

Any idea?

Comment: `In Playground both works but not in the code.` There's no reason for that, it should work the same in an app. My guess is that you have another problem elsewhere - or maybe your values are not what you think they are, check with the debugger.

Comment: Just to mention, it worked long time before using NSURL until I did yesterday migrate the code to Swift3 .

Comment: It works for me with Swift 3 in a test app. [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOw6OBs-sdlFl6y0v4DPhjPGwtfBzMNp2lI)

Comment: The code works fine in simulators and actual devices with Swift 3. What do you get if you put `print(host)` between the two lines.

Comment: It must be something with my Xcode or project settings. Everywhere where I use string interpolation I get empty values no matter all involved variables are properly set

Comment: @OOPer I get correct value, in this case "192.168.1.1"

Comment: just created new test project and all is fine. I am going to investigate what might have gone wrong after the code migration.

Comment: Interesting and odd. What do you get with `print("http://\(host)")` there?

Comment: for me, this worked: let url = URL(string: "http://\(host!)")

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem.

This worked in Swift 2 but broke in Swift 3 (I bounce between 2 of our apps, similar to Facebook & Facebook Messenger):

```
var userId: Int!
var userType: String!

// userId and userType are set by some code somewhere else...

if let url = URL(string: "anotherappicreated://?userId=\(userId)&userType=\(userType)") {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)   // Open our other app
}
```

In Swift 2 implicitly unwrapped optionals (variables declared with the !) worked without having to unwrap them. In Swift 3 it seems you must explicitly unwrap optionals:

```
var userId: Int!
var userType: String!

// userId and userType are set by some code somewhere else...

if let userId = userId,        // <-- HAD TO ADD THIS
    let userType = userType,   // <-- AND THIS
    let url = URL(string: "anotherappicreated://?userId=\(userId)&userType=\(userType)") {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)   // Open our other app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new in swift world, i had that problem too and in my case I declared let constant URL in some other class and swift didn't yell as error. So you can search if you declared twice that var.